# Executing a signal after event loop

Tags: qt, qml

In my .qml file, when a `Button` is pressed, it emits a signal, and some action is taken. This action takes a long time (it is encrypting data) and I want the button to "unpush" itself before this action starts, so I can show a progress bar on top.

I know Qt has event loop, and somehow, I need this signal to be emitted after this event loop , or when the GUI completes the Paint() of all objects, so the button is shown unpressed.

How is this done?

This is the code that is being executed on the signal, the heavy process is `aewm_obj.save_account(key,account)` , it takes 2 seconds on desktop PC and 10 seconds on Android:

```
function save_account() {
    if (fld_password1.length===0) {
        if (account.type==WalletAccount.WACCT_TYPE_FULL) {
            return
        }
    }

    if (fld_password1.text!==fld_password2.text) {
        console.log("passwords do not match")
    } else {
        btn_save.enabled=true;
        if (account.type==WalletAccount.WACCT_TYPE_FULL) {
            key.password=fld_password1.text
            account.password=fld_password1.text
        }
        btn_save.enabled=false
        encrypting_message.open()
        if (aewm_obj.save_account(key,account)) {
            encrypting_message.close()
            accounts_root.back_to_accounts()
        } else {
            encrypting_message.close()
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, the dialog with the progress bar is shown after the heavy process finishes, however it was called before. This happens because the event loop to show and hide components is processed too late.

Comment: Do you execute the heavy process in QML or C++?

Comment: the heavy process is in C++

Comment: then you must execute it in a thread

Comment: hmm, this is a bit complicated, because the user can go to another screen and that's gonna be undefined behaviour... Maybe I can call a timer few milliseconds after button has been pressed?

Comment: can I force a "repaint" of the screen somehow, so my "dialog" with progress bar shows before the heavy process?

Comment: I have edited the question to describe the problem with more detail

Comment: The heavy task must be executed in another thread, that is mandatory in Qt. You must have a class that is responsible only for that task and so you will not have the indefinite behavior that you point out since that object may have a cycle different from the one on the page.

Comment: the code that I show I do not see that it takes so long, most are comparisons, which line consumes 2 seconds?

Comment: he logic to handle a heavy task in general is: have a class that handles the heavy task in another thread, that class will be notified when you want to start processing and that class will signal when the task is finished to another function.

Comment: aewm_obj.save_account(key,account)  function is implemented in C++ and it takes long time due to encryption. On desktop it can be tolerated but not on Android, so I have to show a progress bar before the process starts, but it is not showing up due to that this event is stacked in Qt internally until the c++ process ends.

Comment: the fault is not android, the fault is your design, android has only made it evident, a task that is not considered heavy should take less 10 ms, if it is greater it is considered heavy, if you provide a [mcve] I could help you

Answer (score 1):

Use a single shot timer with a timeout of 0 to queue up an event that will be triggered after returning to the event loop. In C++ this typically looks like:

```
QTimer::singleShot(0, [] { /* do something */ });
```

The QML equivalent is:

```
Timer {
    interval: 0; running: true; repeat: false
    onTriggered: /* do something */
}
```

Comment: Maybe '0' does not work. I am using '10' for such solutions. However this answer should fix the problem.

Comment: @sk2212 "Maybe 0 does not work"?! There is no maybe. Using anything but 0 has larger overhead since it actually creates a system timer, when there is no need for it. All you need is a zero-duration timer, that is not really a timer but an indication that the operation is to be performed after the event queue is emptied.

Comment: In C++, you'd not use a timer, but `QMetaObject::invokeMethod([]{ /* do something */}, Qt::QueuedConnection);`. In QML, `Qt.callLater` does that job - but c.f. [QTBUG-59809](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-59809)!

Comment: Well, using a QTimer::singleShot(0, ...) and doing a the invokeMethod results in exactly the same path taken. I find the 0-timer way more readable than the invoke method.

Comment: actually, `interval` must be something like 50, `running` must be false. But it works nicely. Thanks

Comment: interval:0 doesn't work, and interval:50 shows semi-opaque dialog. I am using interval: 200 and it works nice on Desktop

Comment: @KubaOber Maybe you should change your mind now ;-).

Comment: If interval 0 doesn’t work, then there’s another problem and of course here the real problem is that OP iseems to be blocking the GUI event loop and this should never be done. The encryption should be done using `QtConcurrent::run` or C++11 async primitives. I should have noted that earlier. The button would then have a chance to unpress itself naturally.

Answer (score -1):

After reading this article: https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq27-responsive-guis.html

I have added code to my C++ function to process all the events before it starts the heavy process. This way, I empty event queue and the GUI updates automatically showing the progress bar dialog. (a sort of repaint() of all QML objects)

```
for (int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
    QCoreApplication::sendPostedEvents();
    QCoreApplication::processEvents();
}
```

The delay caused by this loop is unnoticeable compared to the 2 seconds of processing time. The 10,000 iterations are needed on Android, on desktop 10 iterations is enough. Using small amount of iterations, will show the dialog not at full opacity, due to fade effects.

Comment: This seems bad design and not very flexible. Why not use a worker thread and a progress bar? You can disable UI interaction during that time but the UI stays responsive with updates.

Comment: The `processEvents` call exposes your **entire** codebase to reentrancy, and I bet that you didn't design your code with reentrancy in mind. Don't do that.

Comment: reentrancy is when it is interruped by hadware interrupt (or soft interrupt), here, it is not reentrancy, since I am interrupting it in a safe place. During this interrupt the local stack is not being changed, process objects are not being changed. global vars may be changed, but that's why they are global vars. It is just quick patch for the problem, I will rewrite it in the future with a timer on QML side.

Comment: No. Reentrancy means that a function not designed to do so is on the call stack two or more times in a given thread. And `processEvents` can end up calling any method in your code that would be callable as a result of event processing, I.e. timers, UI interaction including windows getting closed, communications – heck, you might start doing application-exit cleanup tasks within that `processEvents`. And you simply should not block the event loop period. Do your computation asynchronously. It’s amenable to it. Use the concurrent pramework of standard C++ async primitives.

Comment: Interrupt handling can cause reentrancy, but is hardly the only way of it happening. Recall that on Windows, event processing can invoke IO completion as well, so both Qt and the OS itself may invoke code you never designed to be invoked.